# How to print each line of a file while adding the nth column to the front of the line to construct an apf ban command

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Bash 4.4.0
Ubuntu 16.04

How to print each line of a file while adding the nth column to the front of the line to construct an `apf` ban command.

Here is my source file called .syncflood-violations.log:

```
[Thu  Nov  14  17:08:19  2019]  SRC=178.128.184.16   DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  SPT=57858  DPT=80
[Mon  Nov  18  19:29:42  2019]  SRC=83.248.31.89     DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  SPT=54667  DPT=40033
[Tue  Nov  19  14:45:11  2019]  SRC=47.92.201.62     DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  SPT=50322  DPT=80
[Wed  Nov  20  14:30:02  2019]  SRC=104.152.52.32    DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  SPT=56417  DPT=5938
[Mon  Nov  25  05:20:42  2019]  SRC=92.246.84.85     DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  SPT=45576  DPT=80
```

Here is some of my script:

```
dmesg -T | grep -- 'INSYN_SRC_LIMIT' | awk '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$11,$12,$19,$20,$21 }' | sed -e 's/PROTO=TCP//g; s/WINDOW.*//g' | column -t | awk '!seen[$6]++' >> .syncflood-violations.log;
sleep .5;
while read -r line; do
  Banip="$(awk '{ print $6 }' | sed -e 's/SRC=//g')"
  #echo "/usr/local/sbin/apf -d $Banip \"$line\""  >> banthem.sh
  echo "/usr/local/sbin/apf -d $(awk '{ print $6 }') \"$line\"" >> banthem.sh
done<.syncflood-violations.log
```

My echo line is not successful.

**Here are my desired results:**

```
/usr/local/sbin/apf -d 58.180.101.13 "[Sat Nov 2 09:36:24 2019] SRC=58.180.101.13 DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX SPT=34345 DPT=80"
/usr/local/sbin/apf -d 178.128.184.16 "[Sat Nov 2 09:36:24 2019] SRC=178.128.184.16 DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX SPT=34345 DPT=80"
/usr/local/sbin/apf -d 83.248.31.89 "[Sat Nov 2 09:36:24 2019] SRC=83.248.31.89 DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX SPT=34345 DPT=80"
/usr/local/sbin/apf -d 58.180.101.13 "[Sat Nov 2 09:36:24 2019] SRC=58.180.101.13 DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX SPT=34345 DPT=80"
/usr/local/sbin/apf -d 58.180.101.13 "[Sat Nov 2 09:36:24 2019] SRC=58.180.101.13 DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX SPT=34345 DPT=80"
/usr/local/sbin/apf -d 58.180.101.13 "[Sat Nov 2 09:36:24 2019] SRC=58.180.101.13 DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX SPT=34345 DPT=80"
```

Comment: `echo "/usr/local/sbin/apf -d $(awk '{ print $6 }' <<< "${line}") >> banthem.sh`

Comment: How about using `echo "/usr/local/sbin/apf -d $(echo "$line" | awk '{ print $6 }')" >> banthem.sh`? Kindly test it once, sorry I couldn't this one.

Comment: @hek2mgl  You are not closing something ... You are missing the ending double-quotes?

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13 the 6th column needs to be in the front of the actual echoed line after the ```/usr/local/sbin/apf -d ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done with single `awk` itself, could you please try following (written and tested with shown samples); you could use `.syncflood-violations.log` file for this code's Input).

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
match($0,/SRC[^ ]*/){
  print "/usr/local/sbin/apf -d " substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-1) s1 substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) s1
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Much appreciated!~

Comment: @CuriousSam, glad that it helped you, cheers and happy learning.